# Difference between Data Mining and a model?

Tags: data-analysis, data-mining

I am pretty much confused with the terms between pattern mining and a model in data mining. For example, I have a number of sequential patterns like below:

No. 1: A->B->C->A = 0.5
No. 2: B->C->D = 0.2
No. 3: A->C->A = 0.1
No. 4: D->C->A = 0.5
....
Say I have found some data patterns like above. I am wondering if I can say they are a model for a sequential pattern mining or they are just patterns in the data. For them to be a model, what should I do?

Comment: What does "$A \to B \to C \to A = 0.5$" mean?

Comment: I just tried to express sequential patterns with ratio for the frequency of each sequential pattern.